# How to display the sku of product in javascript?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, sku, magento-community

When the below line is used in JavaScript it displays the `Product Id`:

> ```
> var productId = optionsPrice.productId;
> window.alert(productId);
> ```

Similarly how to get & display `sku` of the configurable product & simple product?

Answer (score 3):

You need to overwrite **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable** class

```
#app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php

public function getJsonConfig()
{
    $config = Zend_Json::decode(parent::getJsonConfig());

    $productsCollection = $this->getAllowProducts();
    foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $config['products_sku'][$productId]['sku'] = $product->getSku();
    }
    $jsonConfig = Zend_Json::encode($config);
    return $jsonConfig;
}
```

[Updated]

```
#app/etc/modules/SR_Stackexchange.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SR_Stackexchange>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </SR_Stackexchange>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create app/code/local/SR/Stackexchange/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <SR_Stackexchange>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </SR_Stackexchange>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <stackexchange>
                <class>SR_Stackexchange_Block</class>
            </stackexchange>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_type_configurable>SR_Stackexchange_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
     </global>
</config>
```

Create app/code/local/SR/Stackexchange/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php

```
class SR_Stackexchange_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
{
    public function getJsonConfig()
    {
        $config = Zend_Json::decode(parent::getJsonConfig());
        $currentProduct = $this->getProduct();
        $config['sku'] = $currentProduct->getSku();
        $productsCollection = $this->getAllowProducts();
        foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $config['products_sku'][$productId]['sku'] = $product->getSku();
        }

        $jsonConfig = Zend_Json::encode($config);
        return $jsonConfig;
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

[Updated]

Suppose you have all config in var config. So you can display sku following way:

```
// For parent sku
console.log(config['sku'])

//You get all child sku
console.log(config['products_sku']);

//Specific child sku by product_id
var product_id = 294;
console.log(config['products_sku'][product_id]['sku'])
```

Comment: I added your code in configurable.php sir. but the swatches itself got dissappeared.

Comment: did you overwrite base class?

Comment: yes sir. I just added the code which you provided in `public function getJsonConfig()` method

Comment: check updated code

Comment: Yes sir. But When I try to display that in js like `window.alert(sku);` it is not getting displayed.

Comment: check updated code

Comment: no its not getting displayed sir.

Comment: You try configurable parent product sku?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42238/discussion-between-ramya-and-sohel-rana).

Answer (score 2):

In configuable product:

For default theme:
This file:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

will add:

```
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

Now to get the sku you must override the code:

```
<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig(); ?>
```

#### How to override $this->getJsonConfig().

Add an observer name: `catalog_product_view_config`

```
<global>

    <events>

        <catalog_product_view_config>
            <observers>
                <observer_name>
                    <class>yournamespace/observer</class>
                    <method>yourMethod</method>
                </observer_name>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_view_config>

    </events>
</global>
```

In yourMethod implement:

```
public function yourMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $response = $observer->getEvent()->getResponseObject();
    $options = $response->getAdditionalOptions();

    $objCurrentProduct = Mage::registry('product');

    if(empty($objCurrentProduct)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $options['sku'] = $objCurrentProduct->getData("sku");
    $response->setAdditionalOptions($options);
    return $this;
 }
```

Comment: Exactly in which file  should the method be added?

Comment: Using observer is the better way.  You must create the observer in your own module and add the code like: yourMethod implemented above.